# Binary Search an array to display a row of strings in a listview c# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, listview, binary-search

[This image shows what happens after type the name smith and press button search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fed0x.png)I have a CSV text file full of data that is loaded in to an array and displayed in a listview. It has multiple columns and rows. The Columns are ext code, forename, surname. Each row is a different record. I have created a text box that will allow the user to input the surname of a record. Then a **search button** will allow the user to search on surname for extension number. Ideally the program should cope with multiple employees with the same surname, and match on just the first part of the surname; e.g. Sm for Smith and Smyth. It is a basic requirement that searching is not case sensitive.

A binary Search has to be used. 
There are two methods that i tried, however i don't fully understand.
The button should only call the function.
Below is what I have tried, however it is not correct. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  private void searchName()
        {
            Array.Sort(partsTable, (x, y) => string.Compare(x.surname, y.surname));
            Clear();

            int nameIndex = binarySearch(partsTable, txtSurname.Text);

            ListViewItem phone = new ListViewItem();

            phone.Text = (Convert.ToString(partsTable[nameIndex].surname));
            phone.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(partsTable[nameIndex].forename));
            phone.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(partsTable[nameIndex].extensionCode));

            lstOutput.Items.Add(phone);
        }

          private int binarySearch(phone[] partsTable, string Key)
          {
            /* int left = 0;
              int right = partsTable.Length - 1;

              int nameIndex = -1;
              bool found = false;
              while (found != true && left <= right)
              {
                  int mid = (left + right) / 2;

                  if (string.Compare(partsTable[mid].surname, Key, true) == 0)
                  {
                      found = true;
                      nameIndex = mid;
                      MessageBox.Show("If 1");
                  }
                  else if (string.Compare(partsTable[mid].surname, Key, true) > 0)
                  {
                      right = mid;
                      MessageBox.Show("If 2");
                  }

                  else
                  {
                      left = mid;
                      MessageBox.Show("If 3");
                  }
              }
              return nameIndex;
          */
            /* while (left <= right)
             {

                 if (left > right)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Search Failed");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     int mid = (left + right) / 2;

                     if (Key == partsTable[mid].surname)
                         return mid;

                     else if (String.Compare(Key, partsTable[mid].surname) < 0)
                         right = mid - 1;

                     else
                         left = mid + 1;
                 }
             }
             return -2;
             */
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Key = txtSurname.Text;
            int answer = binarySearch(partsTable, Key);
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(answer);
            if (answer >= -1)
            {

                string message = "Extension code already in use";
                string title = "Error";
                MessageBox.Show(message, title);
                extensionCode.Text = string.Empty;
                forename.Text = string.Empty;
                surname.Text = string.Empty;
                lstOutput.Items.Clear();

            }



        }
```

Comment: `if (answer >= -1)` is this condition ever false?

Comment: Also, it looks like all the code in the method is commented out, which means it won't run (and without a `return` statement, it won't compile).

Comment: *"Below is what I have tried, however it is not correct."* Can you state more specifically *how* it's not correct? Are you getting an exception? A compile error? Different results than you expect? If so, what are the results and how are they not what you want?

Comment: @RufusL I don't think it is?

Comment: Use [Array.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch) and create a class implementing IComparer<string> which uses `string.StartsWith(…, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` for case-insensitive prefix comparison.

Comment: @RufusL when I undo the comments for the first method I tried then run the code and search for a correct surname that is in the text file, a message box with "if 3" is displayed. however i need the record of the employee based on that surname to be displayed in the listview. However when i try the second method that is commented out nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo that uses a list to store temp variable(table data). And then use "do ... while" to traverse the list.

```
private void btSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstOutput.Items.Clear();
    do
    {
        searchName();
        if (index != -1)
        {
            people.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
    while (!isnull);
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
    new Person { No = 1, Surname = "Smith"} ,
    new Person { No = 2, Surname = "Smit"},
    new Person { No = 3, Surname = "Bob"},
    new Person { No = 4, Surname = "KKK"},
    new Person { No = 5, Surname = "Obt"},
    new Person { No = 6, Surname = "Peter"}};

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstOutput.View = View.Details;
    people.Sort((x, y) => { return x.Surname.CompareTo(y.Surname); });
}

bool isnull = false;
int index;
private void searchName()
{
    index = BinarySearch(people, 0, people.Count, txtSurname.Text);

    if (index != -1)
    {

        ListViewItem phone = new ListViewItem();

        phone.Text = (Convert.ToString(people[index].No));
        phone.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(people[index].Surname));

        lstOutput.Items.Add(phone);
    }
    else
    {
        isnull = true;
    }
}

List<int> list = new List<int>();

private int BinarySearch(List<Person> p, int low, int high, string key)
{
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (low > high)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        try
        {
            string str = p[mid].Surname.Substring(0, key.Length);
            if (string.Compare(str, key) == 0)
                return mid;
            else if (string.Compare(str, key) > 0)
                return BinarySearch(p, low, mid - 1, key);
            else
                return BinarySearch(p, mid + 1, high, key);
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```